Замена пути к домашней папке пользователя на ~
Есть программа: на вход подаётся рабочий путь через os.getcwd(). Он вернёт условно "C:\Users\Poop\Desktop".
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы выводился изменённый путь. В моём случае это замена домашней папки на ~, как в Linux. Должен быть вывод "~\Poop\Desktop".
Я помню что в библиотеке os была такая функция, но я не могу вспомнить как она называется?

Почему не ~\Desktop?

Можно сперва получить путь с домашним каталогом пользователя, затем найти эту подстроку в строке пути и заменить её на ~.
import os

path = os.getcwd() # C:\Users\Amgarak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
home = os.path.expanduser("~") # C:\Users\Amgarak

if path.startswith(home):
    custom_path = path.replace(home, "~", 1) # ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
else:
    custom_path = path



Каталог /home/andreymal/home/andreymal/home/andreymal жутко недоволен таким решением

@andreymal хорошо, попытаюсь докрутить идею‍♀️

С помощью pathlib.Path:
from pathlib import Path

cwd = Path.cwd()
home = Path.home()
tilda_relative_path  = "~" / cwd.relative_to(home)
print(tilda_relative_path)

